# Copying folder contents from one server to another using Windows PowerShell scripting

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to copy the folder contents from Server 1 to Server 2 using PowerShell scripting. The code is working, but the files inside sub-folders are getting copied outside them.

Probably i am missing something or not doing correctly, as i am beginner to PowerShell scripting.

Could anyone please help for same, below is the code i have tried with:

```
$sourceDir="\\Server1\SourceFolder\"
$targetDir="\\Server2\DestinationFolder\"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $sourceDir |Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir
Write-Host Copied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the following snippet which maintains the sub-folder structure:

$sourceDir="\Server1\SourceFolder\"
$targetDir="\Server2\DestinationFolder\"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse | % {
   $dest = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length)

If (!($dest.Contains('.')) -and !(Test-Path $dest))
   {
        mkdir $dest
   }

Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Force
}